# How to fix "Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous"?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create a Model, but i'm getting a RuntimeError "Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous". I've searched already on other posts about this but could find a working solution so here is my own try.

I am following a tutorial, which is working with the tutorial set of Data.
The code looks as follows:

```
#%% import file

df = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv', sep='\;', engine='python')
df

#%% cleanup

df=df[[ 'CATEGORY','LEFT_ANGLE']]
print(df)
df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

#%%

from tkinter import Variable
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


def sliding_windows(data, seq_length):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(len(data)-seq_length-1):
        _x = data[i:(i+seq_length)]
        _y = data[i+seq_length]
        x.append(_x)
        y.append(_y)

    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

#%%

sc = MinMaxScaler()
training_data = sc.fit_transform(df)

seq_length = 4
x, y = sliding_windows(training_data, seq_length)

train_size = int(len(y) * 0.67)
test_size = len(y) - train_size

dataX = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(x)))
dataY = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(y)))

trainX = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(x[0:train_size])))
trainY = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(y[0:train_size])))

testX = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(x[train_size:len(x)])))
testY = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(y[train_size:len(y)])))
```

This is the DataFrame i want to use for training and the error:

```
[300 rows x 2 columns]
6
CATEGORY    LEFT_ANGLE
0   0   160
1   0   162
2   0   160
3   0   157
4   0   146
... ... ...
295 4   163
296 4   176
297 4   132
298 4   150
299 4   176
300 rows × 2 columns

Cleanup done

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-2bfe2346f838> in <module>
      8 test_size = len(y) - train_size
      9 
---> 10 dataX = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(x)))
     11 dataY = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.array(y)))
     12 


    331             raise TypeError("name must be a string")
    332         global _varnum
--> 333         if not master:
    334             master = _default_root
    335         self._root = master._root()

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

In the first place i dont understand what the class Variable is for and why the Tensor does not accept my array. I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance and sorry if my englisch is not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**:
Remove the `Variable()`

**Explanation**:
I believe your answer is in you question. If you don't know what Variable is, why are you using it? But more importantly you are importing it from `tkinter` which is an interface package and I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

What you want is to use the one from torch.
I was looking for it in the doc but it is actually deprecated, the `Variable()` API from torch now returns a Tensor so it is not useful anymore.
[see here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated)

Comment: After removing Variable() and tkinter i had to restart pycharm, only then the tkinter related error disappeared. Thanks a lot!